# Animation SVG or Canvas?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, svg

I was wondering whether it's better to make an animation like [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas) in canvas or svg (performance wise)? I'm rewriting it now in jquery but I read somewhere that a canvas is redrawn every time it changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For these "simple" animations and scene graphs it doesn't really matter if you use SVG or Canvas performance wise. Both should work fine without performance issues.

However it might be easier to create animation with SVG compared to Canvas. 
In Canvas you have to redraw the whole scene and in SVG you could just create the ring once and then define a transformation (rotation) on it.

For SVG check out [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) or [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and for canvas you can check out [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/), [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/kitchensink/), [kinetic.js](http://www.kineticjs.com/) or [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)

Comment: When you draw a circle or something in a canvas, is it possible to add an event to it in a canvas? And with SVG? Nice examples that you sent :)

Comment: Well in pure Canvas it's not possible to attach events to any primitives/shapes. You have to write code for hit-detection (check if mouse position is inside the circle) yourself. However the above mentioned canvas libraries might support events on shapes as they usually have an abstraction layer. 
SVG supports events on shapes out of the box and that's the reason why interaction is also easier to implement in SVG than in Canvas.

Comment: Alright I think I'm going to use canvas with one of the libraries to add events.